# UITableViewController does not go back to original offset

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am having this rather strange problem. I have an image inside of a `UITableViewCell` and I attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it which detects when the image is tapped.

When the image is tapped, I call `presentViewController()` to present a scaled version of that image inside another view controller. Inside that view controller, where the image is displayed, there is a button that exits the view controller by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated()`.

**My problem** is that everytime I exit the presented view controller, I get thrown into the first table view cell causing losing my original position inside of the tableView, where I tapped the image inside the cell.

What I am thinking of doing, which I assume has little value, is calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` for the UITableView cell but I have a little faith in this approach as I want to resolve the original issue of why I got thrown to the first cell.

**Edit**
I noticed this problem happening only with 8.1 and not 8.3

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the `UIScrollView` documentation. `UIScrollView` contains a property that you can query for the offset. Store that value when you make the segue, so when you `dismissViewControllerAnimated()` you can restore the scroll position.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, however, I am trying to get rid of the root cause